# Functionality related bug

Tags: discussion, bug

Under `REVIEW QUEUES` tab, it shows me `Suggested Edits` have the notification but while clicking on it, no item/question shows me under `Suggested Edits` section.

[image]

Comment: good question, I also face this type of issue many times

Comment: Face same issue today https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDNFG.png

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for such notification. We will look on this topic and will contact with super admin.

Comment: face same issue today https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDNFG.png